# My intellisense does not recognize my #include files even though the project compiles with no problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, unreal-engine5

[I am trying to use f12 to look at the debughelper header but i receive this message when i hover. When i open the project it displays this message in the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65b33.png)

This is for an unreal engine 5 project

I tried to use "Omnisharp: Restart omnisharp" as some posts have suggested but nothing happens. I have opened files using unreal itself as well as directly from the file explorer.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Only a C++ compiler can fully understand a C++ program. Intellisense is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Sounds like your include path might not have been correctly set in the IDE

Comment: Did you edit your `c_cpp_properties.json` to add the additional include directories or are you using CMake and the CMakeTools extension? With that said If you are not using CMake I expect it to be a difficult task in VSCode with such a large and complicated project. You may want to install Visual Studio Community instead.

Comment: IntelliSense is at best a helpful hint, it is often wrong.

Comment: You should probably install regular VS. While it's not perfect (at all), it is still miles ahead in terms of understanding UE++ projects.

Comment: You can try my extension: https://github.com/boocs/ue4-intellisense-fixes